# Support of two or more datacentre

Tags: yugabytedb

Is it possible to create two or more datacentre in yugabyte-db.
Each datacentre having it's own RF and datacentres may be asynchronously replicated. 
We are currently working on a distributed databases where we read or write to a local datacentre if local datacentre fail to served us in that case only geo-datacentre is queried. 
Is this sort of solutions supported in yugabyte. If not then we may face latency in write due to nodes distribution among differently geographical location.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is currently on our roadmap and scheduled for a beta release in 4Q 2019. You can read more about it here: [YugaByte Multi-Region 2DC deployment](https://github.com/YugaByte/yugabyte-db/blob/master/architecture/design/multi-region-2DC-deployment.md)